# How to avoid ui-block div (jquery mobile) to overlap in internet explorer?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have this simple divs, developed in jquery mobile style:

```
  <fieldset class="ui-grid-b"> 
      <div class="ui-block-a">
      <legend>Question 1 haveng a looong text to explain what the user need to answer</legend>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">
          <select name="question1" id="question1">
            <option value='0'>Choose...</option>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    </select>
    </div> 
    <div class="ui-block-c" id="id-error">
        <label for="question1" class="error" generated="true"></label>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a { 
padding-top:20px;   
width: 60%;
}
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-b { 
width: 30%; 
} 
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-c {
width: 10%; padding-top:20px;
}
```

The code represent a page divided in three column (div ui-block-a, ui-block-b, ui-block-c) , occuping respectively 60%, 30% and 10% of the entire page space. All works fine on every browser on earth, but not on explorer. On explorer, if the ui-block-a text is too long, instead of continuing on a new line, it continues *under* the select. How can i avoid the ui-block-a to be overlapped by ui-block-b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe IE is interpretting `fieldset` and `legend` literally as they are intended (with legend being a direct descendent of fieldset - http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset) and is applying some browser specific styling that is messing up your intentions.

If you try this layout with `div`'s instead of fieldset and legend, my guess is it will work.

Since a fieldset's legend is normally rendered by browsers as a floating title at the top of the parent container, interrupting the border (see example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset) I think IE is ensuring this behaviour by forcing the wrap to none.

Comment: You've centerd the issue! Deleting all the legend tag was enough to have the right behaviour on all browser (and i learned something new) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

change the css as

```
div{
   word-break: break-all; 
 }
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a { 
padding-top:20px;   
width: 60%;
float:left;
}
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-b { 
width: 30%; 
float:left;
} 
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-c {
width: 10%; padding-top:20px;
float:left;
}
```

**demo:**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVjqT/)

Comment: thank you very much for helping, but the problem was the behaviour of the legend tag as stated in the answer before yours ^^